# Docker Machine Virtual Box Driver Issue

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-machine

I tried Docker machine for creating bare docker based VM using virtual BOX driver,When I tried changing the network from NAT to Bridge machine start showing error and no IP is assigned to the machine by the docker-machine.In addition to that, when I tried taking SSH of the machine it hangs my terminal. 
Is it only me or every one is facing this problem?
Any solution to that.?

Comment: Why did you change the network? You can always just use a normal linux VM (Ubuntu etc) for running containers if you want.

Comment: Normal VM's took more memory and hard disk and simply to run docker containers, why to install complete OS when you have Docker-machines. I am deploying micro services inside the docker machines so Only one image per docker container.

Comment: I don't really follow this. Are you trying to run multiple docker-machine VMs on a host? Why? And why do you want to change the networking? If you want to play with the settings, use your own VM. You could always use the boot2docker VM image if you're worried about size.

Comment: Yes I am trying to run multiple docker machines VM on a host and my host is in private network and the  default IP assigned by the docker-machine is out of my private network So change the network to Bridge so that the Ip assigned to the docker-machine VM's is under my IP domain,but after doing so docker machine is showing an error and does not show the IP when i fire docker-machine ls command

Answer (score 0):

docker-machine expects the NAT and Host interfaces to be there.

Add the bridged adapter as "Adapter 3" rather than replacing either of the first two. Make sure you select the same *Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop* Adapter type as the other two adapters (under *Advanced*).

You will end up with a third interface, `eth2`. `docker-machine ssh` will still work. You can then access the VM on your real network too.

```
5: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b0:a2:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.1.17/24 brd 10.10.1.255 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```